# How to detect if an ACF custom-field is really in use?

Tags: posts, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, terms

I want to find out if a custom-field is in use for a `post` or `term`.

That means the custom-field has a content and is not empty.

I guess that's more difficult for selects, radio or checkbox-inputs.
So let's imagine i am looking for a text-input field named `my_special_value` and if it is used in any `post` or any `term`.

---

Background:

I got an installation where I want to reduce custom-fields as I expect that some are not in use anymore.

---

Subquestion:

Is there already a plugin for and I didn't found it yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most sensible here is probably just a custom query

*remove `database_name_here.` see comment below.

```php
global $wpdb;

$sql_find_meta = 
"SELECT post_id
FROM database_name_here.wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = 'my_special_value'
AND meta_value > '';"; // > '' == not null, whitespace or blank

$posts_with_meta_key = $wpdb->get_col( $sql_find_meta );

foreach ( $posts_with_meta_key as etc.....
```

You can repeat this for `wp_termmeta` and `term_id`

Comment: was afraid that this would be a SQL thingy. `database_name_here` is not necessary. great, thats really quite easy and short! should also work with all field "types", as data is saved as string only, as i guess.

Comment: Yeah - apologies copied out of my local db terminal - the db name will be selected as part of wp setup

Will leave it in the answer so your comment isn't confusing to someone else

Comment: And - yes it will return anything that's not blank so bear in mind a value of false i.e. not checked / empty for a checkbox will appear in the query as it's still an sql value. `false` `0` or `'0'` will all return - only posts without any data at all will be left out of the results